# Installing Google Maps SDK for iOS via cocoapods causes linker errors

Tags: linker, google-maps-sdk-ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the Google Maps SDK for iOS version 1.3.0 using cocoapods.

Actually the installation process is well succeeded, but when I try to use the framework the app building process returns linker errors, e.g.:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

For some reason the linker can't find the framework. My cocoapods version is 0.20.1. XCode 4.6.2.

Besides Google Maps SDK my project has 2 other libraries added via cocoapods.
Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.1'

pod 'DTCoreText'
pod 'MKNetworkKit'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found it out?

Comment: If you found any solutions than please provide it

Comment: @MehulThakkar Unfortunately I haven't found any solution. I had to upgrade all my tools (cocoapods, google maps version, iOS...) to make it work.

Comment: I have lastly used older version of google maps, that was available with my friend

Answer (score 0):

You should see a file "Pods.xcconfig" which will include the frameworks that the pod is using. Change your app's target configurations to be based on CocoaPods.

Comment: Could you provide example of such changes ?

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMaps to iOS nothing working in iOS < 6.0.

white on Podfile:

> platform :ios, '6.1'
>
> pod 'DTCoreText'
>
> pod 'MKNetworkKit'
>
> pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'